# Symfony Doctrine query error

Tags: php, sql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have the following code:

```
$getmoney = Doctrine::getTable('Countries')->find(1);

$insertmoney = new Accounts();
$insertmoney->userid = $userid;
$insertmoney[$getmoney->getCurrency()] = $getmoney->getBaby(); 
$insertmoney->save();
```

And the query generated by Doctrine is:

```
INSERT INTO accounts (1, userid, 2) VALUES ('0', '31', '15')
```

But it seems to have a SQL error: `1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, userid, 2) VALUES ('0', '31', '15')' at line 1`

The correcy query would be:

```
INSERT INTO accounts (`1`, `userid`, `2`) VALUES ('0', '31', '15')
```

Probably the wrong thing in this is the unfortunate names of the columns, numbers. I had to use numbers only because it make thing *a lot* easier.

What can I do to generate a query that has the columns' names between  " **`** " ?

Comment: Look into generated classes and see if you can put the ` in the column name. But if it does not work - I do not feel sorry for you at all. There is no punishment big enough for naming you columns like that. And no, it does not make anything easier (as you can _clearly_ see).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow... that's quite unfortunate, indeed!
Anyway... you may [configure identifier quoting](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/configuration/en#identifier-quoting) so that you always use backticks.